# Why do some of my apps show "Update" and some show "Update (manual)"?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, google-play-store

When I go into the Market app and into my downloads list I can see that 5 of my apps have an available update.

Three of the apps say "Update" in orange, and two of them say "Update (manual)" in dark red. If I click through to the app I just get the normal "Update" button for both the "manual" and otherwise ones.

I assume this is something new with the Froyo version of the Market, but can't work out what the difference is?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will see Update (Manual) when the app's permissions have changed. So during the Manual update, you should be asked whether you accept the new permissions. Here's a [reference from the Android Market forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=0a9d4cd42a0de921&hl=en). I read this somewhere else but this seems to be the only place I can find it right now. Quoting the link:

> Froyo added an auto-update feature for
> your apps.  If an app has an update
> and no new permissions, it will be
> marked as the orange "update."  If an
> app has changed its permissions, then
> it's red and you need to manually
> update it (after checking and
> verifying the new permissions of
> course).
>
> ...
>
> One more thing, you can verify this when you update your apps.  If the app was a normal
> "orange" update, when you click update, it will start downloading right away.  If the app
> was a manual "red' update, when you click update, you have to agree to the new
> permissions, then it starts downloading.

Comment: Ahhh, so "Manual" just means the update works the same way they all used to pre-Froyo. Nothing scary at all (assuming the permission change isn't outrageous).

Comment: Yeah, for example, Google Sky Map has Update (manual) on my phone right now. After I select Update > OK. It lists the permissions: the app has access to Your Location (fine GPS access), Network Communication (full internet access) and System Tools (modify global system settings, prevent phone from sleeping). I can't figure out which features in the app require use of the Internet but the other two updates are OK with me.

Comment: @GaThrawn Correct.  Manual is just throwing a red flag at you saying "Hey!  Some permissions have changed!  Look at them before you upgrade me!"