# What are "Manual Updates" in Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some of my apps show “Update” and some show “Update (manual)”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2958/why-do-some-of-my-apps-show-update-and-some-show-update-manual)

I have been using Android for a long time now, updating the apps regularly (but not in the "Allow Automatic Update" mode).

Today, for the first time, I came across this:

[image: Option of Manual updates in Google Play Store]

So, my question is as to what exactly are these "Manual Updates" and how do they differ from just "Updates"?

Answer (score 1):

It seams that Apps with updates are shown under "Manual Updates" when the update requires more permission that it's previous versions.

[image: This app's permission has changed to allow access to the following]

A speculative answer to the difference between "Manual Updates" and just "Updates" would be that "Allow Automatic download of updates" does not applies to "Manual Updates".